# Does C handle STDIN with a mutex lock behind the scenes?

Tags: c, multithreading, input, io, mutex

This statement from [*Programming Rust, 2nd Edition*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-rust-2nd/9781492052586/) book has me slightly confused,

> ... the Rust standard library protects `stdin` with a mutex. (Without a mutex two threads trying to read from `stdin` at the same time would cause undefined behavior. C has the same issue and solves it the same way: all of the **C standard input and output functions obtain a lock behind the scenes.** The only difference is that in Rust, the lock is part of the API.)

If two threads in C use `stdio.h` is there any "mutex" behind the scenes that handles contentions on the filehandle? I always thought this was something you had to do explicitly in C, not something that was done for you. Moreover, if you compile a single-threaded C application, does the behavior of these stdio magically change and optimize away the mutex?

Comment: See [getc_unlocked (posix)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getc_unlocked.3p.html)

Comment: On linux, using `glibc`, it _does_ have some linker trickery (e.g. weak symbols/aliases) to make the mutex a NOP for _some_ locking operations. The call is still made but it is a call to a dummy function that just does an immediate `return`. If `-lpthread` is added, the "real" functions will be used.

Comment: Also, see `flockfile/funlockfile`. With these, it is safe to do: `flockfile(fi); while (fgetc_unlocked(fi) != EOF); funlockfile(fi);` even when there are multiple threads.

Comment: @rici thanks exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

### Is there a mutex?

> If two threads in C use stdio.h is there any "mutex" behind the scenes that handles contentions on the filehandle?

C 2018 7.21 7 says:

> Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations performed by multiple threads. Only one thread may hold this lock at a time. The lock is reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time.

### Does a single-threaded application not have a mutex?

> Moreover, if you compile a single-threaded C application, does the behavior of these stdio magically change and optimize away the mutex?

The C standard permits a C implementation to do this, because 5.1.2.3 6 says a C implementation only has to produce the *observable behavior* resulting from a program that behaves as specified in the standard, not that it has to implement a program in the ways described in the standard. I am unaware of whether any C implementations do this. Since modules using `<stdio.h>` may be compiled separately from modules that create threads and then call the former modules, this selection could not be made at compile time unless requested by the user (perhaps by a command-line switch or a `#pragma` directive). It would have to be done at link time (perhaps by linking in a single-threaded version of the standard library) or run time (perhaps by not using any locks until a thread had been spawned).

Answer (score 1):

In versions of the ISO C standard before [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) (published in 2011), there was no concept of multiple threads of execution. Threads were only supported by individual platforms as platform-specific extensions. Therefore, it was up to to the individual platforms to decide how to support multithreading and whether the C library was thread-safe or not.

For example, the Microsoft Windows platform provided two versions of its C library: It allowed you to link with a version of the library which was thread-safe, and one which was not. The non-thread-safe version of the library was intended for single-threaded applications and had better performance, because it didn't need to perform any thread synchronization (i.e. no mutexes).

However, since C11, which introduced the concept of multiple threads of execution, the standard requires that several threads are allowed to write to the same stream at the same time. This means that the C library must be thread-safe in this respect. This requires some form of thread synchronization. Mutexes are often used for this.

> Moreover, if you compile a single-threaded C application, does the behavior of these stdio magically change and optimize away the mutex?

I doubt that it is possible for a compiler to reliably detect whether an application is single-threaded or multi-threaded. In the comments section, it was suggested that certain linker optimizations are performed when not using the `-lpthread` compiler option. However, this will probably only affect [POSIX Threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) and not [ISO C11 threads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is specified in POSIX, not the C standard, but you can see it here

You can see this mentioned in the [2017 POSIX Standrad](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getc_unlocked.html#tag_16_188)

> It would be wrong to have the standard names such as `getc()`, `putc()`, and so on, map to the "faster, but unsafe" rather than the "slower, but safe'' versions. In either case, you would still want to inspect all uses of `getc()`, `putc()`, and so on, by hand when converting existing code. Choosing the safe bindings as the default, at least, results in correct code and maintains the "atomicity at the function" invariant. To do otherwise would introduce gratuitous synchronization errors into converted code. Other routines that modify the `stdio (FILE *)` structures or buffers are also safely synchronized.

On Debian this is detailed in

- [`man 3 stdio`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html)
- [`man 3 unlocked_stdio`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/unlocked_stdio.3.html) An important aside is that `glibc` goes further than even POSIX standard and many of these functions are unstandardized.